# Avoid pagination limits for simple output - Shopify / Liquid

Tags: javascript, ajax, pagination, shopify, liquid

I want to create a simple list of **every** article URL in my blog (I have >150).

My current code:

```
{% for article in blogs['myblog'].articles %}
{{article.url}}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that it only outputs 50 URLs, as per the standard Shopify pagination limit. How could I overcome this? Any solutions using Ajax or otherwise would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the pagination limit simply by wrapping the call with the pagination tag and passing the number you want to paginate.

```
{% paginate blogs['myblog'].articles by 999 %}
  {% for article in blogs['myblog'].articles %}
    {{article.url}}
  {% endfor %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

**PS**: Please note that the more articles you have the longer it will take for the DOM to load.

Comment: I have noticed that this solution doesn't work if you are on a specific page e.g. www.website.com/blogs/myblog?page=2 - it doesn't generate any pagination results. Works fine if you are on www.website.com/blogs/myblog

Comment: @DevOverflow it's normal not to work if you don't have more than 999 articles. When you are on page 2 it will show 1000-1998 articles and if you don't have those it will be empty.